# Панель на весь экран имеет по краям просветы

Tags: unity3d

Подскажите почему может панель на весь экран имеет просветы по краям?
Изначально она выключена, в анимации панель включается и меняется её прозрачность.
Настройки на скриншоте. На устройстве так же.

[image: рис1]

Минимальный воспроизводимый пример: https://yadi.sk/d/HYHCY3ELJfpkGQ

Comment: Проверил у себя - все работает. [Минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) можете предоставить?

Comment: Вы уверены, что по иерархии ничего не находится поверх пустого черно спрайта?

Comment: ...и измените `RectTransform` объекта со спрайтом с "По центру" на "Растягивать" (щелкните по иконке в левом верхнем углу в компоненте)

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема заключается в неправильной настройке панели "на весь экран", потому что на самом деле она у не на весь экран, а с конкретными размерами (1136*758) и "По центру".

Да, настройка для канвы (`Canvas Scaler`) "по умолчанию" 1136*640 и сохранение размера по ширине, **но!** в настройках экрана "Screen" установлено соотношение сторон 3:2, а это означает, что `CanvasScaler` установил размер канвы в 1136*(1136/3x2) => 1136*~757.3f. С вещественными типами могут быть погрешности в округлении, поэтому и получилось, что "панель на весь экран" дает небольшой зазор.

Исправьте настройки `RectTransform` объекта с черной заливкой на "Расстягивать":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не помогло.

Comment: Тогда просто необходимо посмотреть на иерархию ваших объектов. Обновите вопрос, прикрепите более подробную информацию.

Comment: я добавил информацию.